# twitter bootstrap drop down menu horizontal links

Tags: jquery, iphone, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

i have used twitter bootstrap to develop responsive css
can you tell how to develop the drop down menu with links on horizontal direction instead of vertical direction

Please Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/AJ5JW/) page

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </a>
          <a class="brand" href="#">
            <img alt="change" class="defieLogo" src="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/defie_logo_only.png">
          </a>
          <div class="nav-collapse in collapse" style="height: auto;">
            <ul class="nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="/docs/examples/product.html">Product</a></li>
              <li><a href="/docs/examples/solutions.html">Solutions</a></li>
              <li><a href="/docs/examples/services.html">Services</a></li>
              <li><a href="/docs/examples/partners.html">Partners</a></li>
              <li><a href="/docs/examples/partners.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form pull-right">
              <input class="span2" type="text" placeholder="Email">
              <input class="span2" type="password" placeholder="Password">
              <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in</button>
            </form>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not extactly sure if this is what you're looking for as it's a click dropdown instead of a :hover. Test it on clicking "Products" nav item.

jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AJ5JW/1/

Changes:

```
      <li class="dropdown active"><a href="/docs/examples/product.html" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Product</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="http://">Hi1</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://">Hi2</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://">Hi3</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
```

Starts on line 1424, the vertical "mobile" view transitions nice as well.

Utilized this http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar

Comment: Also just realized you asked for horizontal links on the "dropdown", so I may have been mistakin in what solution you're trying to achieve.

Comment: :thanks for ur reply https://docs.google.com/a/defie.co/file/d/0B3IBJKENGE7Rek83cllzdHJmYkk/edit i wanted sth like this